# Publishing status reverted from Success to Waiting for deployment

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1-hr1

We have observed one very strange issue. Business scheduled approx 100 pages through schedule in phases where they schedule to render at one time and publish at later time.

> The publishing went through fine and all transactions were successful.
>   After some time, transaction status was changed to waiting for
>   deployment in publishing queue and then it is stuck in that state.

To validate the publishing was actually successful, we went to Odata to verify the last published date and it was updated based on timings. Also, we have event system to capture data for successful transactions, there also it was updated as success.

Can you please suggest what could be the issue in such scenario.

Comment: are you absolutely sure it is the same publish transcation, and not a new one with the same item(s)?

Comment: Yes, sure about it as I checked publishing queue at time of occurrence and what I saw were only transaction in waiting for deployment. Also, time of published matched with lastpublished in odata.

Comment: Tracing this back will be hard, I've never seen such an issue. Only thing I can think of is that there have been some rollback of servers/databases that would bring a transaction back in progress.

Comment: I would not think database rollback as that means the updated data should not be seen in odata.

Comment: Odata is a complete different database, the publish queue is in the cm database. Plus I'm mearly sharing my thoughts, could be anything.